# Динамическое значение в текстовом поле GUI Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, tkinter, textbox

Необходимо создать окно *Python*, в котором было бы текстовое поле, которое получало бы изменяющиеся значения. 
Например, курс валют или погода, которая в реальном времени отображалась бы в текстовом поле и обновлялось без нажатия на кнопку.

Вот пример кода.

```
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()
window.title("Прога")

lbl = Label(window, text="Привет")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: 1) Google поиск:  tkinter entry keypress event

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()
window.title("Прога")

labelText = StringVar()                                                # +++
# lbl = Label(window, text="Привет")
lbl = Label(window, textvariable=labelText)                            # + textvariable=labelText
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
i = 0
def updateDepositLabel(i, txt="Привет"):                               
    labelText.set(txt)                                                 # +++
    i += 1
    text = f"Привет {i}"
    window.after(1000, lambda: updateDepositLabel(i, txt=text))    

window.after(0, lambda: updateDepositLabel(i, txt=f"Привет {i}"))
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

window.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @BitcoinEarn что не так?

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import Tk, Entry, Label


class App(Tk):
    text = ''
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        entry = Entry()
        entry.grid()
        entry.bind("<Key>", self.handle_entry)

        self.label = Label()
        self.label.grid()

    def handle_entry(self, key):
        # cprint(key.char)
        self.text += key.char

        self.label['text'] = self.text


def main():
    App().mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```